# How to set enum val of fixed size to its max possible value?

Tags: c++, enums, bitmask

This is probably simple but I'm not getting it right. I have a "bitmask" enum which has a value `all` that indicates that all bits are set. However, I can't get it to flip all bits using ~0. The following error appears:

```
<source>:11:16: error: enumerator value '-1' is outside the range of underlying type 'uint_fast8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'}
   11 |         all = ~0x0,
      |
```

Which is strange because it should actually fit into uint8_t no? Here is my code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MYdnT7hbh)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum mask_t : uint_fast8_t {
        first = 0x1,
        second = 0x2,
        all = ~0x0,
    } mask;

    mask = all;
}
```

Comment: A `uint8_t` has a range of `[0, 255]`, which `-1` is not in.  Try doing `all = static_cast<uint_fast8_t>(-1)`

Comment: Or you can use `std::numeric_limits<type_wanted>::max()`

Comment: `~0x0` (`-1`) would make `all` have a value of `0xFF` (`255`, `b11111111`), but since `mask_t` only has 2 defined values, it might make more sense for `all` to have a value of `0x3` (`3`, `b00000011)` instead, which you can get from `all = first | second`, or just hard-code it: `all = 0x3`. It depends on how `all` is being used in the rest of the code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then you'd have to remember to update `all` whenever you add new values to the `enum`. With an `all` with all its bits set, it already covers any new enum values you might add.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "*you'd have to remember to update `all` whenever you add new values to the enum*" - true, which is not the end of the world. But it really depends on how `all` is being used elsewhere. I generally prefer to use masks that actually mask only *supported* values and don't allow *unknown* values. On the other hand, there are cases where you may want to mask all possible bits even though some values are reserved for future expansion. Context matters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think you're probably right. The name of the type is `mask` so it could be surprising if `all` couldn't actually be used to mask to only get the enum's flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `0x0` is of type `int`. So if you try to flip all the bits you'll get `-1` which can't be assigned to the type your enumeration was defined to.

Even if you use a suffix for that literal value, like `u` for example. To indicate that the literal value is of unsigned type. As in `~0x0u`. You'd get the maximum of the `unsigned int` type. Which exceeds the range of the 8-bit integer type you're using. So this doesn't work either.

So you need to tell the language that you want the literal value to be of the type you need first. That can be achieved with a `static_cast` as demonstrated in other answers:

```cpp
static_cast<uint_fast8_t>( ~0x0 )
```

But using hardcoded types and values can get in the way sometimes if you decide to change the type of the enum later. So if you have c++14 available. You can use the `std::underlying_type` type-trait and make a generic utility like:

```cpp
template < class T > constexpr std::underlying_type_t< T > enum_max_v = ~static_cast< std::underlying_type_t< T > >(0);
// If you have c++17 available with the inline keyword
// template < class T > inline constexpr std::underlying_type_t< T > enum_max_v = ~static_cast< std::underlying_type_t< T > >(0);
```

And then used like:

```cpp
enum mask_t : uint_fast8_t {
    first = 0x1,
    second = 0x2,
    all = enum_max_v< mask_t >,
} mask;
```

Now you don't have to care about the underlying type of the enumeration.

You can even use `std::numeric_limits` if you want the right values instead of relying on flipping bits:

```cpp
template < class T > constexpr std::underlying_type_t< T > enum_max_v = std::numeric_limits< std::underlying_type_t< T > >::max();
```

Sky is the limit.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the maximum value with the help of some meta-programming tricks

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

enum mask_t : uint_fast8_t {
  first = 0x1,
  second = 0x2,
  all = std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<mask_t>>::max()
} mask;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EcTqrj568)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the expression `~0x0` having the type `int` and a negative value to the type `uint_fast8_t` like for example

```
all = static_cast<uint_fast8_t>( ~0x0 ),
```

Why does the expression have the type `int`? Because the integer literal `0x0` has the type `int` and the operator ~ does not change the type of the expression.

From the C++ Standard

> 2 The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding
> list in Table 5 in which its value can be represented.

And an object of the type `int` can represent the literal `0x0`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
        
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<int, decltype( 0x0 )> << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Another way is just to write

```
all = 0xff,
```

Comment: I think this may fail if the target type is bigger than `int`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why should it be bigger?  There is used an operation with an object of the type int.

Comment: If you tried with a different type like `uint64_t` where `int` is 32 bit I think `all` would only have 32 of 64 bits set. Consider `all = static_cast<uint64_t>( ~0x0 )` when `int` is smaller than `uint64_t`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux See my updated answer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I was not asking about the type of `~0x0`. I was mentioning that if you replace `uint_fast8_t` with another type that is larger than `int`, or if `uint_fast8_t` happens to be larger than `int` somehow, then I think the solution probably stops working. If you had `all = static_cast<uint64_t>( ~0x0 )` instead it probably wouldn't work if `int` is not 64 bit.

Comment: If negating ~doesn't change the type of expression, why does `~static_cast<uint_fast8_t>(0x0)` not compile?

Comment: @glades That is a result of integer promotion. Basically arithmetic on integer types smaller than `int` get the operands cast up to `int`, and the result cast back down to the operands' common type. Here the result would of the cast is converted to `int` but it fails to cast back down to `uint_fast8_t` due to it not being able to represent that value.

Comment: @glades Due to the integral promotions the operand of the expression with the operator ~ is promoted to the type int and you have the same problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok but when I do static_cast I can be sure that "cutting off the superfluous bits" is done internally? Also, what if I take 64bit as underlying value? Will the bits set via ~0 in the 4 integer bytes be filled with 1 for the full 8 bytes?

Comment: @glades It is unimportant what will be the type. The problem is that unsigned integer types can not represent negative values.